# Why is my System.Data.Entity namespace blank for c# projects?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a c# asp.net MVC project.it was given to me as a plain old asp.net project which I upgraded to MVC 3. Normally I use vb.net for my projects but this was handed to me as a c# project. In all my projects I create a base repository that uses generics and can handle almost all basic situations, the table it quotes is represented by a member variable of the type IDbSet in the System.Data.Entity namespace.  This has always worked fine in my vb projects. In this project I am getting a compile error stating that the type is not recognized and asking if I am missing a using directive or assembly reference.

When I try to define the variable explicitly specifying the namespace like so:

```
protected readonly System.Data.Entity.IDbSet mObjectSet;
```

I still get the error, I get intellisence after System. and after Data. but once I type Entity. I get nothing. I have tried cleaning and rebuilding, restarting visual studio, restarting my computer. And there doesn't seem to be a single related issue on google. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit:

I should have mentioned that I have a reference to version 4.0.0.0 of System.Data.Entity already.

Comment: Missing (read: need to add) a reference?

Comment: I vaguely recall running into this, but don't recall the solution.  Look at your Build output (not just the Errors window) and see if there are any other errors.

Comment: @MitchellKrenz: And restarting Visual Studio doesn't help?

Comment: The error i'm getting is:
error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'IDbSet' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data.Entity' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: @John Gathogo, No, but I got the answer I needed, see below. Thanks!

Comment: @MitchellKrenz: Glad you found the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[IDbSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679233%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) interface lives in `EntityFramework.dll` assembly (not in `System.Data.Entity.dll` assembly, be attentive!). Just add reference to it (`References` folder in project tree, then right click and choose `Add reference` or use NuGet package manager, if you've already installed it).

Comment: I should have mentioned that I have a reference to version 4.0.0.0 of the dell already.

Comment: AFAIK, there was no `EntityFramework.dll` version 4.0.0.0, since `EntityFramework.dll` is an "extension" (which provides Code First approach API) of `System.Data.Entity.dll`. 

Are you confusing IDbSet with IObjectSet interface (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642094.aspx, it is defined in `System.Data.Entity.dll`)?

Comment: You are correct, not only did I misread your comment but also the MSDN page when I looked at that earlier to check which assembly it was in, I should really get some sleep haha, also this is why I hate being handed a project rather than creating it myself. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have **System.Data.Entity** reference

**EDIT**: I think you need either version 3.5.0.0 or 4.0.0.0

Comment: I should have mentioned that I have a reference to version 4.0.0.0 of the dell already.

Answer (score 0):

Also note that VS 2010 by default creates a entity framework 4.0 ( within System.data.entity) entity model,
and vs 2012 creates a entityframework 5.0(within EntityFramework.dll) model.